# node.js : memcached error handling

Tags: node.js, memcached

I wrote the following structure I use to set cache.

```
memcached.get(cacheKey, function (err, data) {
  //DO SOMETHING IF DATA
  if (data) {
    //DATA FOUND
  } else {
  //REQUEST BASE
    var result = ...;
    memcached.set(cacheKey, result, constants.LONG_CACHE, function(err) {
      //DO SOMETHING IF CACHE CAN'T BE SET
    })
  }
})
```

My question is how do I check if memcached is still running on a server to handle the memcached crash problems? Looking at the docs, it looks like there is a method "connectionIssue" that I probably can use.

Comment: I have the same problem. After deleting the memcached node, it just gives me undefined data but no error.

Comment: I'd like to help you but I don't really understand my question anymore -.- But I surely was able to fix it.